# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars in a dataset loading

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am sorry, but I am quite new withing the community. So it might be that this question could be trivial.
Anyway, I have created a numpy matrix. Now I would like to evaluate the density points by using the meanshift algorythm.
Unfortunately I am currently facing the following error:
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

```
    nygrid=np.zeros((2501,901), dtype=int)
       for x in range(0,39):
       in_file = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Master en BIGDATA\Trabajo Fin de 
       master\Practica\Data Records\part-m-000" + '{:02d}'.format(x)
       for line in open(in_file):
      passen, forigen, corigen, fdest, cdest = line.split('\t')
      vPass=int(passen)
      vFOrigen=int(forigen)
      vCOrigen=int(corigen)
      vFDest=int(fdest)
      enter code herevCDest=int(cdest)
    nygrid[vFOrigen][vCOrigen]=nygrid[vFOrigen][vCOrigen]+vPass
    nygrid[vFDest][vCDest]=nygrid[vFDest][vCDest]+vPass
```

#### Now the matrix nygrid is loaded

```
    from sklearn import datasets
    import mean_shift as ms
    model = ms.MeanShift(kernel_func=ms.gaussian_kernel, bandwidth=50, 
    seeds=500, n_jobs=-1)
```

Creation of variable columns and rows
       columns=nygrid[:,:901]
        rows=nygrid[:2501,:]

Now I have to create the X and y and the idea would be to pass the whole rows and the whole columns of the matrix as n_samples and centers
       X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=rows, centers=columns, 
       cluster_std=np.random.normal(1, .3, n_clusters))

Now I get the following error, realizing that I cannot pass the variable rows and columns as n_sample and centers.

```
     X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=rows, centers=columns)

    File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda2\lib\site-
    packages\sklearn\datasets\samples_generator.py", line 752, in make_blobs
    n_samples_per_center = [int(n_samples // n_centers)] * n_centers

    TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

It might be that the logic is not accurate in order to launch tha meanshift. But as I told you I am brand new in this area.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error with:

```
In [29]: int(np.array([1,2]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-26c1a90e530a> in <module>()
----> 1 int(np.array([1,2]))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

In

```
int(n_samples // n_centers)
```

one or both of `n_samples` and `n_centers` is an array.  The `//` is integer division, and the result is an integer array.  It's an error to try to convert that to one integer (which is what Python `int` function does).  And there's not need to attempt this conversion. Plus `astype(int)` is the correct way to convert a float array to integer.